# getting three errors

Tags: c

This code is showing following errors:

> 1. missing ) before type
>
>    2. calc: too few arguments to call
>    3. syntax error ) Visual stuio 2013 platform

MyCode:

```
  #include "math.h"
    void main()
    {
        float num[5];
        float (calc (float num[5]));
        calc(float num);/* transferring control to calc function)*/
        getch();
    }
    float calc(float nun[5])
    {
        int i;
        float num[5];
        float sum, avg, sqmn1, sumsqmn = 0, sqsd = 0; float sd;
        printf("\nEnter 5 numbers");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
        {
            scanf("%f", &num[i]);
        }
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
        {
        sum = sum + num[i];
        }
        avg = sum / 5;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
        {
        sqmn1 = (avg - num[i])*(avg - num[i]);
            sumsqmn = sumsqmn + sqmn1;
        }
        sqsd = sumsqmn / 5;
        sd = sqrt(sqsd);
        printf("\nThe sum is %f", sum);
        printf("\nThe average is %f", avg);
        printf("\nThe stabdard deviation is %f", sd);
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: ugh. which code...? ok, the chunk of lines above? we're human, not compilar, please, Format your code kindly.

Comment: how would you like it to be edited sir?

Comment: don't call me sir, i'm a lady. :-). and don't worry about the edit, it's been taken care already.

Comment: Syntax errors usually come with line numbers; use those to fix your errors.

Comment: Try a forward declaration of `calc` outside the main function instead, like this: `float calc(float num); //Then the main function`

Comment: It looks like you're confusing a function declaration with actually calling the function, as indicated by Natasha below.

Comment: In your `calc` function, you pass a parameter named `nun` and have a local variable named `num`.  Do you think those names are awfully similar and confusing??  You never use the variable `nun`.

Answer (score 3):

`float (calc (float num[5]));`

in your `main()`, what is this exactly?

IMO, it can be,

```
float ff;
ff = calc(num);
```

Other than that,

1. `#include <stdio.h>` is missing.
2. Forward declaration of `float calc(float nun[5])` is missing.

You can rewite your `main()` as

```
int main()
    {
        float num[5];
        float ff;
        ff = calc(num);/* transferring control to calc function)*/
        getch();

        return 0;
    }
```

but then also, you're passing `num` from `main()` to `calc()` but i see you never used it. What are you upto?

Comment: `float (calc (float num[5]));` is a forward declaration. It should be moved outside `main`. It is good practice to place forward declarations outside function definitions. Also, the superfluous parenthesis should be removed: `float calc(float num[5]);`

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thank you for adding that. by seeing that the returned value is not being captured, i though otherwise.